# Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined- Redux Persist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-persist

The more specific error I am getting is this : Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `store` is marked as required in `Provider`, but its value is `undefined`.

store.js

```
const initialState = {};

const storage = createSensitiveStorage({
  keychainService: "myKeychain",
  sharedPreferencesName: "mySharedPrefs"
});

const config = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const middleware = [thunk];

const reducer = persistCombineReducers(config, rootReducer);

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
  );
  let persistor = persistStore(store);

  return { store, persistor }
}
```

index.js for reducer:

```
export default combineReducers({
    profile: profileReducer,
    auth: authReducer,
    photoSlider,
    trip: tripReducer,
    moment: momentReducer
})
```

App.js:

```
import {store, persistor} from './src/store';

<Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <Layout />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the lines in App.js where you get your `store` and `persistor` variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `store.js`, you don't export `store` and `persistor`, you export a function that returns an object with a `store` and `persistor`. So your `import` statement in `App.js` actually imports two *named imports* that don't exist.

You can get your instances like this:

```
import factory from './src/store';

const {store, persistor} = factory();

<Provider store={store}>
  <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
     <Layout />
  </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

Comment: hi @sylvain i have imported correctly but still am getting this error. Can you tell me some suggestion?Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Johncy! May I know if you managed to solve the issue? I have tried this and https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/979, but it is still to no avail. Thanks a heap!

Comment: Still I didn't get a solution for this due to I moved to React Native. I just removed the PersistGate component from render function..:((

Comment: Hey @Johncy! I got it running. I spelled "persistor" as "pesistor". It was just a small typo!

Comment: @erwinleonardy
So sad...:))